# I am getting "undefined" while adding charcters in my array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

Here is my code can someone just explain why I am getting undefined?? I have split the words and then reverse them and after reversing I tried to store them in a different array.
Thank you

```js
const text = document.querySelector("#text");
const reverseText = document.querySelector("#reverseText");

let words = text.innerHTML.split("").reverse();
console.log(words);
let reversedWords = [];
let counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) {
  if (words[i] != " ") {
    reversedWords[counter] += words[i];
  } else {
    counter++;
  }
}
console.log(reversedWords);
```

```html
<p id="text">hello nixit</p>
<p id="reverseText"></p>
```

Comment: Yes I got it I already console.log(reversedWords[counter]), but what's the reason for that.

Comment: Because you start with an empty array

Comment: [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) exists. :)

Comment: @sean-7777 I'm sure OP's aware of that because they're already using it... `split("").reverse()`

Comment: Yes I already know that solution, but I was trying as a challenge for not using it

Comment: @Phil, could guide me what could I do to avoid that undefined!!!!!

Comment: @stacknexo oh ok then @Phil 's comment is right. when you `+= val` to a empty array, `arr[0]` is undefined, so you have the undefined thing. to avoid you can do `arr[0] = arr[0] ? arr[0] + var : arr[0]`. cleanest way i can think of

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that the first time you try and access `reversedWords[counter]`, it is `undefined` because you've initialised `reversedWords` to be an empty array.

Without changing much of your code (because you said you're doing it this way as a *challenge*), you could try initialising `reversedWords` to have the appropriate number of elements, initialised to empty strings

```js
const content = text.textContent;
const words = content.split("").reverse();
const reversedWords = Array.from({ length: content.split(" ").length }, () => "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using an array so you need to `push` things into it, and then `join` it up into a new string once the iteration is done.

```js
const text = document.querySelector('#text');
const reverseText = document.querySelector('#reverseText');

function reverse(str) {

  // `split` the string on the spaces
  const words = str.split(' ');

  const reversedWords = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

    // For each word split, reverse, and then rejoin it
    const word = words[i].split('').reverse().join('');

    // And then add the word to the array
    reversedWords.unshift(word);
  }

  // Return the completed array
  return reversedWords;
}

const str = text.textContent;
reverseText.textContent = JSON.stringify(reverse(str));
```

```html
<p id="text">hello nixit</p>
<p id="reverseText"></p>
```

Additional documentation

- [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift)

Comment: but I want to keep both words differently in an array like ["tixin","olleh"]

Comment: Updated answer @stacknexo

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a string instead of an array. Then you can split it to turn it into an array.

```js
const reversedChars = 'hello nixit'.split("").reverse()

const reversedWords = ''

reversedChars.forEach(char => {
    reversedWords += char
})

const reversedWordsArray =  reversedWords.split(' ')

console.log(reversedWords)
// Output: tixin olleh
console.log(reversedWordsArray)
// Output: [ 'tixin', 'olleh' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @phil and @Andy,
I am new learner who will learn and read all the use of Array.from() and than use it, but till than I have made something like this.

```js
const text = document.querySelector("#text");
const reverseText = document.querySelector("#reverseText");

let words = text.innerHTML.split("").reverse();
let reversedWords = new Array();
let counter = 0;
let firstChar = 0;
for (var i = 0; i <= words.length - 1; i++) {
  if (words[i] != " ") {
    if (firstChar === 0) {
      reversedWords[counter] = words[i];
      firstChar++;
    } else {
      reversedWords[counter] += words[i];
    }
  } else {
    firstChar = 0;
    counter++;
  }
}

reversedWords.forEach(word => reverseText.textContent += word + " ");
```

```html
<p id="text">hello nixit
  <p>
    <p id="reverseText">
      <p>
```